# Firebase CLI questions and [FlutterFire CLI] CLI doesn't find Firebase CLI

Tags: flutter, firebase, cmd, firebase-cli

I am trying to connect Firebase with my flutter app.
for this, firebase takes me to install firebase CLI.

Question1: is there another way?

I downloaded `firebase-tools-instant-win.exe` and everytime I want to run firebase command, I have to run it.

Question2: is it the right way? because normal cmd, does not recognize its commands. I cant seem to put my environment variables on the right path.

Then, in AndroidStudio, inside the folder containing my app, I run `flutterfire configure --project=projidy2`.

Question3: FlutterFire CLI asks me to install Firebase CLI even if it is already installed, and logged in my account.

```
E:\android\webrtc_tutorial>flutterfire configure --project=projidy2
i Found 0 Firebase projects. Selecting project projidy2.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version 
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/do
cs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.
```

```bash
flutterfire --version
0.2.7
```

```bash
firebase --version
11.20.0
```